# How to bake in cycles render?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, baking

I made this object and I'm trying to bake a diffuse texture so the textures will all be on 1 image but for the love of god nothing works. I made the object, I unwrapped it good, I have the image texture node hooked up to the uv map node for each material, hit bake and the pieces come out black instead of the texture colors. What am I doing wrong?

https://gyazo.com/b8a164de21a373c87ba4bc3bbe4c3777

Comment: Do you have lighting in your scene, or are you attempting to bake without a light source? You might then try an emission shader in your materials so that your texture is shadeless perhaps?

Comment: There is no lights in the scene.

Comment: You need light or you won't get anything.

Comment: How much light should I add?

Comment: Do you need to get shadows into your texture, or are you looking for something that has no lighting in it? If the latter, then use an emission shader instead of a diffuse shader for baking with, and that will act like a shadeless shader in blender render. Then you can bake and save your texture, and return to using a diffuse texture. If the former, then you will need to light and set Ambient Occlusion, etc. to taste and then bake.